# Make rewrite rule accept only lower case

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

How can I make this rewrite rule accept only lower case?

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/?$
```

I tried doing .*/i for the first part. But it wont work. It still lets uppercase thru:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2}.*/i)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9()_\-.]+)/?$
```

Comment: Could you post the whole rewrite rule?

Comment: RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9()_\-.]+)/?$ /print/print_arc.php?t=$1&m=$2pc=$3 [NC,L]

Comment: Ok. So it;s the [NC] that was causing the problem. So how do I tell it to accept only lower case? Remove the NC?

Comment: Ok. I got it working. Thanks for pointing me to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your `RewriteRule` is followed by [the `[nocase]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc), the matching should be case-sensitive. So your first rule is supposed to work.

Note that it is NOT possible to add flags using the PHP-/JS-style `/i`. The latter would match a literal slash followed by a lower-case `i`.